# php read mongodb.findone() returned json values and create object

Tags: php, json, mongodb, object

I have an employee class and i want to initialize the employee object from mongodb.findone() returned array.

```
foreach($res as $key => $value){
    echo $value; // here values printed
}
```

but i need to do something like( if key = 'first_name' then employee_obj->set_first_name($value), if key = 'last_name' then employee_obj->set_last_name($value)... ) can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$employee = new Employee;

foreach($res as $key => $value){
    if (property_exists($employee, $key)) {
        $employee->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

`$employee->$key = $value` is dynamically assigning `$key` property to the employee. Example:

```
    $key = "name";
    $employee->$key = "John Doe";
    echo $employee->name; // John Doe
```

If you want to do this with private or protected properties you need to do the assignment within the class or instance:

```
class Employee {

    // ...
    private $name;

    // lets you assign properties by passing in an array
    public function __construct($arr = array()){
        if count($arr) {
            foreach($arr as $key => $value){
                if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
                    $this->$key = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$joe = new Employee(array('name' => 'Joe'));
echo $joe->name // Joe
```

Comment: what is employee->$key ? my employee class have private member m_first_name is this gonna assign $value to this?

Comment: Edited with some more detail, hope this answers you question.

Comment: it's really-really cool,,, but I have a "bad" tradition to start members name with m_. in my case names are different.

Comment: It´s just an example, you can name your properties (members) whatever you wan´t.

Just beware if you ever do this with user input as it needs to be whitelisted to avoid a mass assignment vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

```
$e = new Employee;
foreach($res as $k => $v){
    if($k == 'first_name'){
        $e->set_first_name($v);
    }elseif($k == 'last_name'){
        $e->set_last_name($v);
    }else{
        $e->$k = $v;
    }
}
```

Does exactly that.

Comment: of course does,,, but is this a good way? i mean everytime checking the $key is not an effective way, is it?

Comment: @MherDidaryan well there are different ways, for example many frameworks allow you use the magic __get to actually make `$e->last_name = "sam"` refer to `$e->set_last_name("sam")` But without coding deeper into the PHP language you won't get better